# Django: how to display error only once when user enter invalid information on form submition?

Tags: html, django, htmx

may someone tell me how to avoid to have the error message shown 2 times?
I'd like to keep the top error message, but on red.

[image]

https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T07EFKXHR-F058SR427RA/image.png

**html:**

```
<form hx-post="{{ request.path }}" class="modal-content p-4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Ingresa tu usuario y clave</h5>
  </div>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ login_form.as_p }}
    {% if login_form.errors %}
        <ol class="">
            {% for field_errors in login_form.errors.values %}
                {% for error in field_errors %}
                    <li class="text-danger"><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    {% endif %}

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

form.py:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Nombre de usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Contraseña'}))
```

view.py:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        print("### Request is post")

        if login_form.is_valid():
            print("### Request is VALID")
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            print("User name", username, "type: ", type(username))
            print("Pass", password, "type: ", type(password))
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Trigger': 'user_logged_in'})
        else:
            return render(request=request, template_name="account/email/login_form.html",
                          context={'login_form': login_form, 'errors': login_form.errors})

    else:
        login_form = LoginForm(request)
        context = {
            "login_form": login_form,
        }
        return render(request=request, template_name="account/email/login_form.html",
                      context={'login_form': login_form, 'errors': login_form.errors})
```

**UPDATE 1:**

not rendering explicitly the errors in HTML, leaves me without errors at all.

May be something related to HTMX usage?

[image]

```
<form hx-post="{{ request.path }}" class="modal-content p-4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Ingresa tu usuario y clave</h5>
  </div>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ login_form.as_p }}


<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

image:

Answer (score 0):

Django renders the errors by default within `{{ login_form.as_p }}`. It would be quite error-prone if the errors would need to be rendered explicitly, as it's easy to forget about it.

So there are the errors rendered once, and the second time they are rendered becuase you do that explicitly yourself via inside the block `{% if login_form.errors %} ... {% endif %}`

Comment: Please, see update 1.

Comment: how does your View look like?

Comment: I've edit original question to add view.

Comment: does the form render with errors as expected when you not use htmx to submit it?